# Conservation of Energy for Uniform Circular Motion in a Vertical Plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

I was considering the energy and work done on an object experiencing uniform circular motion in a vertical plane, eg. a ball on a string swung vertically, and I arrived upon these conclusions:

- The kinetic energy must be constant as $K=0.5mv^2$ and since the object is moving in UNIFORM circular motion the magnitude of the velocity is constant.
- The gravitational potential energy, $U$ must change as the object varies in height

Though, as this is a closed system, the mechanical energy (sum of $K$ and $U$) must be conserved - however, this does not seem to be the case as the $U$ varies whilst $K$ is constant.

Does this imply that an external force has been applied to the system? How else can you account for this discrepancy?

Comment: What makes you think the kinetic energy is constant? Clearly as the ball rises towards the highest point gravity acts to slow it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinetic energy is not constant because velocity is not constant.  Centripetal force is defined as the force required to keep an object moving in circular motion.  Hence, centripetal force must vary.  In the formula $T-mgcos\theta=\frac{mv^2}{r}$, $v$ varies as $\theta$ varies.

Hence, energy is actually conserved; when the ball is at its lowest point, velocity is highest, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this imply that an external force has been applied to the system?
>   How else can you account for this discrepancy?

Yes. Without an external force the speed and thus the kinetic energy would vary with height - precisely because, as you point out, the total energy is constant in a closed system.